# Placing a Custom Post Type Menu Above the Posts Menu Using menu_position?

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, wp-admin, admin, admin-menu

I just figured out the [menu_position parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) it seems like you can place the menu of your custom post type almost everywhere. Except above the Posts menu!

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Good question, it seems that is the one place it won't go.

Answer (score 28):

**Positions for Core Menu Items**

- 2 Dashboard
- 4 Separator
- 5 Posts
- 10 Media
- 15 Links
- 20 Pages
- 25 Comments
- 59 Separator
- 60 Appearance
- 65 Plugins
- 70 Users
- 75 Tools
- 80 Settings
- 99 Separator

**Parameter description for "menu position"**

> `$position` ([integer](http://codex.wordpress.org/How_to_Pass_Tag_Parameters#Integer)) (*optional*) The position in the menu order
> this menu should appear. By default, if this parameter is omitted, the
> menu will appear at the bottom of the menu structure. The higher the
> number, the lower its position in the menu.
>
> **WARNING:** if two menu items
> use the same position attribute, one of the items may be overwritten
> so that only one item displays! Risk of conflict can be reduced by
> using decimal instead of integer values, e.g. 63.3 instead of 63.
>
> *Default: bottom of menu structure*

Comment: How to use decimal In 'menu_position' =>3,? I wanna use position=3 for many custom post types.

Answer (score 4):

The new JetPack Plugin places its menu link immediately below the Dashboard link. It does so by [setting its menu order to 0, by filtering the $menu_order array](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/jetpack/trunk/jetpack.php):

```
function jetpack_menu_order( $menu_order ) {
        $jp_menu_order = array();

        foreach ( $menu_order as $index => $item ) {
            if ( $item != 'jetpack' )
                $jp_menu_order[] = $item;

            if ( $index == 0 )
                $jp_menu_order[] = 'jetpack';
        }

        return $jp_menu_order;
    }
```

Out of curiosity, what would happen if you tried 0 as menu_position?

Answer (score 4):

Looking for a solution on the web but didn't found. Simply does this trick (for example). Here you have the native list of positions:

> - 2 Dashboard
> - 4 Separator
> - 5 Posts
> - 10 Media
> - 15 Links
> - 20 Pages
> - 25 Comments
> - 59 Separator
> - 60 Appearance
> - 65 Plugins
> - 70 Users
> - 75 Tools
> - 80 Settings
> - 99 Separator

If you have more items, you can read the current position for each items by printing the global $menu :

```
global $menu; 
print_r($menu);
```

So if I well understand, nothing can prevent us too re-order the menu like we want :

```
function re_order_menu () {
    // ------- Put away items 
    $dashboard = $menu[2]
    $separator1 = $menu[4]
    $posts = $menu[5]
    $media = $menu[10]
    $links = $menu[15]
    $pages = $menu[20]
    $comments = $menu[25]
    $separator2 = $menu[59]
    $appearance = $menu[60]
    $plugins = $menu[65]
    $users = $menu[70]
    $tools = $menu[75]
    $settings = $menu[80]
    $separator3 = $menu[99]

    // -------- Reset menu  
    unset($menu[2]);
    unset($menu[4]);
    unset($menu[5]);
    unset($menu[10]);
    unset($menu[15]);
    unset($menu[20]);
    unset($menu[25]);
    unset($menu[59]);
    unset($menu[60]);
    unset($menu[65]);
    unset($menu[70]);
    unset($menu[75]);
    unset($menu[80]);
    unset($menu[99]);

    // -------- Re-order menu as you want
    $dashboard = $menu[2];
    $separator1 = $menu[4]
    $posts = $menu[5];
    $books = $menu[6];
    /* my tons of custom items */
    $authors  = $menu[7];
    $requests = $menu[8];
    $clients = $menu[9];
    $sellers  = $menu[10];
    $services = $menu[11];
    $schedules = $menu[12];
    /* let some space after */ 
    $media = $menu[30];
    $links = $menu[31];
    $pages = $menu[32];
    $comments = $menu[33];
    $separator2 = $menu[59];
    $appearance = $menu[60];
    $plugins = $menu[65];
    $users = $menu[70];
    $tools = $menu[75];
    $settings = $menu[80]
    $separator3 = $menu[99];

} 
add_action('admin_menu', 're_order_menu');
```

It works fine for me so, I think this is legit, I'm wrong ?

Comment: Very fragile solution which relies on [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_\(programming\)). It would break as soon as some other plugin is added/removed that places an item amongst the others.

Answer (score 2):

I've used 'menu_postion' => 0, 1,2,3,4.

Doesn't matter really. If you play around with it you can easily figure it out.

Using 'menu_position' => 1 should place it below the Dashboard menu item above the separator thing. 0 Should place it above the Dashboard

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in WordPress. Please see this thread in Trac: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14755

Fixed in 4.4...

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/#notes

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
function my_move_post () {
    global $menu;
    $menu[6] = $menu[5]; //move post from post 5 to 6
    unset($menu[5]); //free the position 5 so you can use it!
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_move_post');
```

Now you can use position 5 to add you menu above Post menu.

Comment: This did not work for me. I placed it within my sitewide plugin where my custom-post-type.php file is

Answer (score 1):

here is the caveat to the whole issue...

**WordPress 4.9.2**

wp-admin/menu.php:

```
// If we're to use $_wp_last_object_menu, increment it first.
$ptype_menu_position = is_int( $ptype_obj->menu_position ) ? $ptype_obj->menu_position : ++$_wp_last_object_menu;
```

NOTICE: must be an integer and NOT set already, otherwise it goes to the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 1):

For a working solution in WordPress 5 and below, reposition it with the following code:

```php
add_filter('custom_menu_order', '__return_true');
add_filter('menu_order', function($menu_order) {
    if (
        false !== ($k1 = array_search($v1 = 'edit.php', $menu_order))
        && false !== ($k2 = array_search($v2 = 'edit.php?post_type=foo', $menu_order))
    ) {
        array_splice($menu_order, $k1, 0, $v2);
        array_splice($menu_order, $k2 + 1, 1);
    }
    return $menu_order;
});
```

This assumes you don't have more than one menu item vying for pole position.

Answer (score 0):

On the same link you linked, it reads:

```
menu_position
(integer) (optional) The position in the menu order the post type should appear.
Default: null - defaults to below Comments
5 - below Posts
10 - below Media
20 - below Pages
60 - below first separator
100 - below second separator
```

So, if you set `menu_position` to something like `4`, then it should put it above posts.

A position of `-1` puts it above the `Dashboard` link.

Comment: I tried 4 but it exactly the same as 5.

Comment: Hrm. Tried 1-3? I think perhaps "1" (or "0") is the Dashboard. Perhaps something 2-3 would work

Comment: 0 1 2 3 Goes before the Dashboard and 4 Goes below Posts. Is really impossible!

Comment: Wow. broken much WordPress? I don't know then. :-/

Comment: I think that 4 is the separator right above Posts, and 5 is Posts, so if you set your menu-position to 3 it will be right before the separator. With default configuration of course. Setting my plugin page to 4 overwrote the separator, but did appear just above Posts. hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

You can use decimal values (as strings). For example, I have some custom post types that I placed at the last position in menu (100001, 100002, 100003).

Then, just put this code to move them above *Posts* and below *Dashboard* menu items.

```
function reorder_admin_menu() {

  global $menu;

  // Add one separator

  $menu["3.1"] = array(
    0 =>  '',
    1 =>  'read',
    2 =>  'separator_' . "anything_unique",
    3 =>  '',
    4 =>  'wp-menu-separator'
    );

  // I have put my menu items waay at the end (exactly these values), so move them up

  $menu["3.2"] = $menu[100001];
  $menu["3.3"] = $menu[100002];
  $menu["3.4"] = $menu[100003];

  unset($menu[100001]);
  unset($menu[100002]);
  unset($menu[100003]);

  // move Media menu (position 10) item to front, in the same group
  $menu["3.5"] = $menu[10];
  unset($menu[10]);

  // Debug: ksort($menu); error_log( var_export( $menu, true ) );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'reorder_admin_menu', 999 );
```